# Is it a theorem that $\ n^{(n-1)^p} \equiv 1\pmod {n-1} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

<s>Is it a theorem that $\ n^{(n-1)^p} \equiv 1\pmod {n-1} $ $\ n,p \in \mathbb Z^+ $</s>

For example
$$\ 4^{3^p} \equiv 1\pmod {3} $$

This seems to be true empirically but I have no idea if it has been proven.  I can't find anything about it. I was also wondering if $\ a = n, \ b =n-1 \ $are the only solutions to the congruence$$\ a^b \equiv 1\pmod b$$ Any information is appreciated.
I now realize that my first question is obvious but am really more interested in my second question about the positive integer solutions of the above congruence.

Comment: Well, since $n\equiv 1 \pmod{n - 1}$ it follows immediately.

Comment: Hint: $\bmod n-1\!:\,\ n-1\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, n\equiv 1\ \ $

Comment: In general, $n^k\equiv1\pmod{n-1}$. One can prove this from the even more general principle that $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$, $c\equiv d\pmod{n}$ implies $ac\equiv bd\pmod{n}$, and induction. So what you're trying to calculate is reduced to just $1$ multiplied by itself lots of times.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \equiv 1 \mod b$ then $a^k \equiv 1 \mod b$ for all $k>1$. This is because $\mathbb Z / b \mathbb Z$ (the integers "modulo b") forms a [ring.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) We can prove that statement quite easily for $k\geq 0$: Since $a \equiv 1 \mod b$ there is some $m$ such that $a + m\cdot b=1$. Therefore

$$a^k = (a+mb)^k = \sum_{n=0}^k \binom{k}{n} \underbrace{a^n (mb)^{k-n}}_{\text{divisible by $b$ for all $n<k$}} $$

and so $a^k \equiv a \equiv 1 \mod b$.

To answer your second question: No that is not necessarily the only solution. Consider the case $3^4 \equiv 81 \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Comment: Isn't $2^5 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 $

Comment: I assume it should have read $2^4 \equiv 1 \ \mod 5$, which is true.

Comment: @Charles, but my question is specifically asking for the power and modulus to be the same.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Now I'm wondering if there is an example.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when answering your second question, check out the updated version.